# Plotting histogram of brownian motion?

Tags: python, histogram, physics

My task is to plot a histogram of the simulation of brownian motion. Thankfully, I've already made a program that simulates brownian motion, and plots it on a scatter plot as a function of time and distance. This is what my output looks like:

[image: Brownian motion]

However, I need to convert that to a histogram, for 5 different locations (e.g: histogram at t=0,1,2,3,4).

Currently the packages I have are numpy, mattplotlib, and scipy. I have seen examples of how to plot a normal distribution, but how do I plot a distribution for the data that I have gathered?

Here is the code I have so far: http://pastebin.com/AEpQDQd2

(Since I couldn't post two links, I had to paste both files together, the first one is the one that does the computation for brownian motion and the second is the one that outputs the graph that is on the imgur link)

This is not for homework, but it was given as an extra credit problem, and the instructor explicitly said we are allowed to use whatever information we can.

Thanks.

Comment: Please try to elaborate more on what your coding-problem is. Do you know how to access the data that you want ot plot? Do you understand the `hist` method of matplotlib? Can you generate its input parameters? At which point do you get stuck?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. Basically my problem is that I didn't know how to use a histogram for my specifically data. I had seen several examples of how to plot a normal distribution, or a binomial distribution, but not any examples where a user had used a histogram to plot their very own data, and that was what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pylab.hist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) something like this, after calculating the index of the time point you're interested in, `it`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy
from pylab import plot, xlabel, ylabel, title, grid, show, hist, legend
from brownian import brownian

#This is the code that performs the main iteration of the Euler Marayuma process, from t=0 to t=10.

def main():

# The Wiener process parameter.
    delta = 2
    # Total time.
    T = 10.0
    # Number of steps.
    N = 500
    # Time step size
    dt = T/N
    # Number of realizations to generate.
    m = 1000
    # Create an empty array to store the realizations.
    x = numpy.empty((m,N+1))
    # Initial values of x.
    x[:, 0] = 0

    brownian(x[:,0], N, dt, delta, out=x[:,1:])
    t = numpy.linspace(0.0, N*dt, N+1)

    # time points of interest
    ts = [4., 3., 2., 1.]
    for t in ts:
        it = int(t/T * N)
        hist(x[:, it], alpha=0.7, label='%.1f s' % t, normed=True)
    legend()
    show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

(You may care to plot the histograms on separate figures and/or make the bin size constant across your time points.)

Comment: Make sure to normalize the histogram -- the histogram on itself is uninformative (because the number depends on the choice of bins), while the probability distribution is the relevant number.

Comment: That's a good point: one should add normed=True to the call to hist.

Comment: Thank you so so so much. This works just as I desired.